Losing ability to edit random sites - 2019 SP On-Prem
Sharepoint Server 2019 v16.0.10337.12109 on Windows Server 2016.
I have an issue that has been plaguing us for over a year now where we have sites that we are no longer allowed to edit despite having the permissions to, I've verified the permissions by doing a check and also tried as the farm admin account. What's worse is the problem seems to be spreading to different sites and we're not sure why. Sites we used to be able to edit to we can no longer edit, there is no option to edit and it is acting like a read-only copy. I've used Chrome and Edge and other admins are able to duplicate the issue. These page are not checked out or anything like that.
As an example, let's say I have a site called Test and I want to edit it, when I click the gear and click on either Site information, Site permissions, or Change the look, nothing happens. If I hover over say Site information, on the bottom left of the browser it shows the following:
javascript:_spLaunchSiteSettings();

I noticed if I click into a library and hit the Follow button (underneath my name), it says:

Wait a minute To follow documents or sites, we need to get a couple of
things set up. This can take a few minutes to complete, and once it's
done, you'll need to come back to this site and try following again.

I hit Get Started and get this error:

Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.TECHNICAL
DETAILS Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: ID string Date and Time: 5/17/2024 11:02:39 AM

If I add the following to the end of the site, I am unable to edit it:
ToolPaneView=2&Mode=Edit

(IE: /SitePages/Home.aspx?ToolPaneView=2&Mode=Edit)
We decided to try and give a department a new site as a workaround and and were immediately unable to edit it as well.
We're not sure what suddenly brought this on as we made no major changes during any of this. Restoring sites to a previous and working point in time does not resolve it so I am leaning heavily towards a system issue. Previously I ran the SharePoint Configuration Wizard but that didn't help.
